# What should be app URL vs organisation URL?

Tags: urls

I have created an App. Let's say MyApp.

Now, what should be URL for the app?

The name of the organization is also the same. Let's say "myapp Inc".

So what is the best practice to display organization info and app to put into URL?

To be more clear, should app URL be like:
app.myapp.com

and organization URL be like:
www.myapp.com

Comment: Hi! Thank you for posting on ux.stackexchange. The URL is part of the Web user interface and you can find articles about some rules like the fact you'll need a domain name that is easy to remember and easy to spell, short URLs. However, I think you could be a little more specific. Do you want to know if it is better to have a subdomain for a web app or if you should link the screens for a native app to your web pages?

Comment: app is not live yet. but yes question is. what subdomain or domain should it be. like facebook doesnt have business specific page. but it contains app on facebook.com. but i have a business page to show with same name as app to clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of the cases are like you mentioned, or www.domainname.com/app

If you have single landing page, you can just use www.domainname.com for client presentation as informal site. And then just have direct login, or login with extension /login... domainname.com/dashboard can be start of your app etc.

If you wanna go fancy, depending who your public is, you can have extension of (www.domainname.io, for internet organisation).

Having app for subdomain, or for extension is also less important than having appropriate domain name (short, memorable, describable for your business).

Comment: I don't see anything fancy with using the .io domain. I don't think that's anything worth considering.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the example you've added is quite common to see nowadays.

Platform: app.myapp.com

Commercial site: [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)

I would say that in general it's a good practice to separate the platform from the commercial site in the url, it will make things easier for your tech-savvy & frequent users to quickly access it and easier to track for your team too.

But still I would recommend to consider some aspects before making the call of using app.domain.com:

- Does the company has some expectations to grow the product suite in the future? If so, how the other apps will be integrated into the url? Would it make more sense to be more specific about what the platform is or does? Take Google Suite example: docs.google.com, analytics.google.com, etc.
- Is there a specific app per user that should have different urls? For example, if your product were a learning platform it could make more sense to use something more action driven: teach.myapp.com, study.myapp.com, etc.
- How tech savvy is your audience? Will they easily remember the 'app' a bit?